# How can i get someone telegram chat id with python?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

Hi everyone i want to create a new telegram bot similar to @usinifobot.
this is how it works:
you just send someone username to this bot and it will give you back his/her chat id.
i want to do same thing but i dont khow how to do it with python-telegram-bot.

Answer (score 0):

python-telegram-bot can't help with this, because telegram bot api can't provide ids of unrelated entities to the bot - only ones with which bot iteracts

you need telegram client api for this and to hold a real account (not a bot) online to make checks by another library

and with bot library like python-telegram-bot you could only get ids of users who write to bot, channels and groups bot is in and reposted messages from other users

I created similar bot @username_to_id_bot for getting ids of any entity and faced all these moments

Comment: I don't write on python, it is in node.js. As for python for connecting as a client you can use telethon or pyrogram or find a python wrapper for tdlib. And your program should be both a bot with token and a client with telephone number, both modules iteracting with each other